# Angular Animation Directive

Tags: angularjs, animation, directive

I'm trying to write an angular directive that will animate a list of words similar to  http://codepen.io/rachsmith/pen/BNKJme . However, I'm needing to load the text from a json file and then select a random sentence to apply the animation to. I have this part working, but am having trouble accessing the directive's child elements. I am assuming this is because the directive is being called before the elements are rendered, but using scope.$on($viewContentLoaded, function... has not made a difference.

I have jQuery and Underscore available.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
Data.sentences().then(function (response) {
    var sentences = response.data;
    $scope.sentence = _.sample(sentences);
});
```

**View**

```
    <div class="rotator">
        <p>{{sentence.static}}</p>
        <text-rotator>
            <span class="word" ng-repeat="item in sentence.options">{{item}}</span>
        </text-rotator>
    </div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('textRotator', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var words = el.children('.word');
            //cannot access array of items with class of word
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to get the directive work as you wish?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, the `ng-repeat`-ed *words* are not yet in the DOM at the time the `link` function of the directive is executed. The `sentence` object is fetched asynchronously.
Listening on `$viewContentLoaded` won't help: this is an event fired by `ngRoute` module when the content of the `ngView` is loaded. After a digest cycle followed by DOM updates due to a change on the model, this event is not fired.

Actually, I think you're creating yourself troubles as the data could be (should be) passed as a parameter to the directive. The child word elements would be the template of the directive. I suggest something like the following:

```
app.directive('textRotator', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            options: '='   
        },
        templateUrl: 'words.html',
        link: // ...
    }
});
```

**Template:**

```
<text-rotator options="sentence.options"></text-rotator>
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/w3Lvmj13/2/) might help you. The animation part has been replaced by a simple toggling of the opacity. Also, the words are mocked in the controller, you should make sure they are *resolved* by the router in the definition of the route / state, or otherwise you would have to add a watcher in the directive.